# Visualize Project Dependencies in Visual Studio for Mac?

Tags: .net, dependency-management, visual-studio-mac

I'm using **Visual Studio for Mac**, and I want to create a picture of our numerous .NET C# Projects that visually shows the dependency graph.

It appears I can do this in Visual Studio (for Windows) with [Code Maps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/modeling/map-dependencies-across-your-solutions?view=vs-2022). But from that article I don't see Visual Studio for Mac support.

**Q)** How can I create a .NET project dependency graph on my Mac?

**VS Version Info**

- Visual Studio Community 2022 for Mac Preview
- Version 17.3 Preview (17.3 build 2012)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you have a Windows machine, just copy your DLLs there and analyze them with the standalone app VisualNDepend.exe (that comes with NDepend redistrib). Start VisualNDepend.exe > StartPage > Analyze .NET assemblies in Folder > Wait a few seconds > Dependency Graph panel
 https://www.ndepend.com/docs/project-dependency-diagram